# Returning the Number of Records after a Delete/Insert Operation in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, count

I want to return the number of records before and after an operation performed in a Stored Procedure. I looked up a function that should have worked for returning the number of rows in a table. But, it ain't working. Any help?

Similar: [Please check this link on DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18274/returning-row-count-in-a-stored-procedure-in-oracle)

The procedure only consists of Dynamic SQL (execute immediate commands). The code is too large to paste here (and confidential).

The real motive is that I want to know how many records did a table consist of before the insert/delete command (in an execute immediate) and how many records it consisted after the insert/delete operation.

I want to store the logs of the procedure in another table (a kind-of log table) which keeps a track of the number of rows inserted/deleted from the table being operated on.

e.g.

```
PROCEDURE_NAME         OP_TYPE    RUN_DATE             RECORDS_BEFORE   RECORDS_AFTER
Name of the procedure  Type of    Operation Performed  1103929          1112982
```

The procedure body.

```
create or replace procedure vector as 

begin

-- select count(*) from some_table 

execute immediate 'delete from some_table
where trunc(creation_date) >= trunc(sysdate) - 7';

execute immediate 'insert into log_table values
(''Procedure Name'',''Insert'', sysdate,''....'')';

-- select count(*) from some_table

execute immediate 'insert into some_table ....';

execute immediate 'insert into log_table values
(''Procedure Name'',''Insert'', sysdate,''....'')';

-- select count(*) from some_table

end vector;
```

Basic requirement: I want the count(*) of some_table to be inserted into the log_table.

Comment: Please show the procedure you're using and define 'not working' more in terms of what behaviour you expected; what behaviour you observed; and what, if any, error messages were produced.

Comment: You need to expand a little more on what exactly you have in mind. If you want to get a number of records affected by a DML statement, use `SQL%ROWCOUNT` implicit cursor attribute. To get the number of records before(Why?) any DML is executed you need to query a table.

Answer (score 1):

what data exactly do you want to get?

If it is the number of rows affected by your command - it should be in SQL%ROWCOUNT (after each individual command you execute. It will not "sum" all the modifications in the procedure, if this is what you need -you'll have to sum it manually after each insert/delete/update).

But, if you want to have the total number of rows in the table - you should run a

```
SELECT count(*) from TABNAME
```

before and after the command you executed (with the performance hit of it).

You can also combine the two - run a count(*) in the beginning of your procedure, and use SQL%ROWCOUNT to count the numbers of rows you modified , and assume the table now has count(*) - rowcount(of deletes).

DO REMEMBER that the Oracle by default will show you the number of records in the table at the time the count(*) query is being executed (after executing the current transaction commands), so the changes you will see without using the rowcount might include concurrent changes. For more information read about Oracle isolation level http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2005/05-nov/o65asktom-082389.html .

In addition - there'd might be a concurrent change between the time you ran the count(*) query and the "delete" / "update" clause - so think about the scenarios that might occur in your specific case.

If you want a more detailed / code review - update the relevant part of the procedure / queries you execute.